# getting error on node js while try to run a chat package

Tags: node.js

I am new in node js. I am trying to run a package which I have downloaded from github: [Mobile chat with Sencha Touch](https://github.com/mrsunshine/Mobile-Chat-with-Sencha-Touch---node.js---socket.io-).
But when I tried to run the server js I found lots of packages missing. I have install those packages one by one. But now I got a strange error, please have a look.

```
root/node/mobile_chat/server.js:13
    Connect.conditionalGet(), // Add HTTP 304 responses to save even more bandwid
            ^
TypeError: Object function createServer() {
  function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
  utils.merge(app, proto);
  utils.merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
    app.use(arguments[i]);
  }
  return app;
} has no method 'conditionalGet'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/node/mobile_chat/server.js:13:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

Can anybody have any idea about that error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like a version conflict to me, did you check the dependencies?

Comment: check the version of connect you are using.

Comment: As well version of Node.js can cause some problems.

Comment: Nodejs has changed a lot in recent years. That repo was last edited 3 years ago, making it almost certain that it was built for a much older, incompatible version of nodejs.

Comment: ...and it's missing a package.json

Comment: https://github.com/mrsunshine/Mobile-Chat-with-Sencha-Touch---node.js---socket.io-/issues/3 This error appears to have been around for at least a year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:) For the sake of answering this question: The package is over 3 years old stated by @joshua-anderson and you are getting the error because the newest connect version does not have the `conditionalGet`.

You have a better chance trying this package, not sure if it's something you are looking for. Looks similar: [sencha-touch-chat](https://github.com/rzen/sencha-touch-chat) (last commit 3 months ago)

Good luck with your nodejs adventures!